# Explain this code I found on the internet to me?

Tags: java

I came across the following implementation ( https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/40371/easy-dp-java-solution-with-detailed-explanation ), but not quiet understanding how it works — commented on how I got lost:

```
boolean isMatch(String s, String p) {
    if(s==null || p==null) {
        return false;
    }

    //  Why add an additional length to the string lengths?
    boolean[][] dp = new boolean[s.length()+1][p.length()+1];
    dp[0][0] = true;

            //  What’s the reason for this check? If p were to have ‘*’ at i=3, it would simply pass
    for(int i=0; i<p.length(); i++) {
        if(p.charAt(i)=='*' && dp[0][i-1]) {
            dp[0][i+1] = true;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<p.length(); j++) {

            //  Shouldn’t dp[i][j] just equal to true? Why set a boolean value to characters ahead? 
            if(p.charAt(j)=='.') {
                dp[i+1][j+1] = dp[i][j];
            } 

            //  Same question as prior
            if(p.charAt(j)==s.charAt(i)) {
                dp[i+1][j+1] = dp[i][j];
            } 

            if(p.charAt(j)=='*') {
                //  Not quiet understanding what the following checks are for and how they work
                if(p.charAt(j-1)!=s.charAt(i) && p.charAt(j-1)!='.') {
                    dp[i+1][j+1] = dp[i+1][j-1];
                } else {
                    dp[i+1][j+1] = (dp[i+1][j] || dp[i][j+1] || dp[i+1][j-1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you in advance and will be sure to vote up/accept answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure how you got lost is that some dope said _solve this riddle_ then proceeded to give conditions based on language conditionals and array positions ie. `If p.charAt(j) == s.charAt(i) :  dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];` Stay away from these mindless know nothings. !! Spend your time with a purpose, where the end result is some code.

Answer (score 1):

Q:*Why add an additional length to the string lengths?*
A: **For clearer code.**

Q:*What’s the reason for this check? If p were to have ‘*’ at i=3, it would simply pass*
A:**It stands for: if first character in the pattern has matched first character in the string, mark as many as possible characters of string as matching. It's greedy approach.**

Q:*Shouldn’t dp[i][j] just equal to true? Why set a boolean value to characters ahead?*
A:**Nope. It's because we don't want to indicate that character matches if something before didn't match. Simply, if 3 character of the input doesn't match, nothing following it, shouldn't be marked as matching.**

Q:*Not quiet understanding what the following checks are for and how they work*
A:**If the character differs from previous one, and the previous pattern character isn't a dot which has special meaning, keep the state, as we could have 0 length match. Otherwise, just keep going in one of three possible directions (look behind, above or in front).**